# Jsp page is returning null object to controller

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

I am new to Spring MVC and I am trying to create a small app that gets some info from this [page](http://graph.facebook.com/pivotalsoftware). I have two buttons: "Display Page Info" button where on click it goes to `GetPageInfo` method in the `PageController`, and "Save" button where it takes the displayed info, validate them using `@Validated` annotation, and if they are validated, it calls another jsp page which is pageSaveSuccess.
Here's my code:

```
@Controller
public class PageController {

    @Autowired
    private PageService pageService;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("pageValidator")
    private Validator validator;

    @InitBinder
    private void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        binder.setValidator(validator);
    }

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public ModelAndView showPage(){
        Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        return new ModelAndView("page", model);
   }

    @RequestMapping(value= "/getPage", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView GetPageInfo(@ModelAttribute("page") PageVO pageVO, ModelMap model) {
        Page page = pageService.GetPageInfo();
        pageVO = convertToVO(page);
        System.out.println("Page name Service: " + pageVO.getName());
        model.addAttribute("page", pageVO);
        return new ModelAndView("page", model);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/savePage", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String savePage(@ModelAttribute("page") @Validated PageVO page, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {
         System.out.println("Saving the Page info: " + page.getName());
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            System.out.println("Returning page.jsp page");
            return "page";
        }
        System.out.println("Returning pageSaveSuccess.jsp page");
        model.addAttribute("page", page);
        return "pageSaveSuccess";
    }

    public PageVO convertToVO(Page page) {
        PageVO pVO = new PageVO();
        pVO.setName(page.getName());
        pVO.setAbout(page.getAbout());
        pVO.setPhone(page.getPhone());
        pVO.setWebsite(page.getWebsite());
        return pVO;
    }
}
```

And the jsp page is:

```
<form:form action="savePage" commandName="page" method="POST">
    <input type="button"  onclick="location.href='${pageContext.request.contextPath}/getPage'" value="Display Page Info" >
    <ul>
        <li>
            <label style="width: 75px">Name</label><input type="text" value="${page.name}" style="margin: 8px 100px 5px 100px; width: 200px;" /> 
        </li>
        <li>
            <label style="width: 75px">About</label> <input type="text" value="${page.about}" style="margin: 8px 100px 5px 100px; width: 400px;" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <label style="width: 75px">Website</label> <input type="text" value="${page.website}" style="margin: 8px 100px 5px 100px; width: 200px;" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <label style="width: 75px">Phone</label> <input type="text" value="${page.phone}" style="margin: 8px 100px 5px 100px; width: 200px;" />
        </li>
    </ul>
    <input type="submit" value="Save"/>
</form:form>
```

The problem is that when I click on "Display Page Info" the info are displayed well in the text boxes but when I click on "Save", the page object is null when it arrives to `savePage` method because the console shows this log: `Saving the Page info: null`.

What is my mistake? How can I return the page info that I already displayed in the jsp page?
Thanks.

Comment: `System.out.println("Saving the Page info: " + page.getName());` printing `Saving the Page info: null` does not mean page is null, just that page.getName() is null !

Comment: mmm Yes you're right, but why it's not returning the properties of the page? I mean the name, website, phone...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add *name* attributes to your input fields, e.g.

```
<input type="text" value="${page.name}" name="name" style="margin: 8px 100px 5px 100px; width: 200px;" />
```

as an alternative you can use form input tags

```
<form:input path="name" />
```

the only thing is that the form:input doesn't support *value* attribute, but from I see in you controller methods, initial values should be already set on the object

Comment: Still facing the same issue even after adding name="page".

Comment: If adding name attribute to <input> tag, add them as name="name", name="website", name="about", name="phone"